# How can I run “server side includes” with Grunt and Grunt-Connect?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I’m running a tiny server using Grunt and `grunt-contrib-connect`. I have an HTML file — and a second HTML file which is being generated from Markdown via Grunt. I want the first HTML file to “include” the generated HTML file. I don’t care if this is a build step or dynamic thanks to the server (I suspect only the former may be a supported configuration).

I know this should be simple, but… What‘s the best way to simulate "include" in an HTML file with Grunt?

Comment: https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up testing with this: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ssi

It is a pre-compiler. I had numerous issues with other modules and this seemed to work best.